# How to move a selected item in qt with mouse click events

Tags: c++, qt, chess

I am working on a chess gui and want to be able to move the selected piece from its original location to a selected destination tile. How can I select the piece I want to move and move it to a clicked tile? The chess board is a 2d matrix.

Here is how the chess board is initialized

Board:

```
void BoardView::initBoard(){
    //setBackgroundBrush(Qt::black);
    QGraphicsRectItem* board{this->addRect(0, 0, 8*CellView::TILEHEIGHT, 8*CellView::TILEWIDTH)};
    addItem(board);

    QColor squareCol{m_white};
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
            (i+j) % 2 == 0 ? squareCol = m_white : squareCol = m_black;

            std::shared_ptr<CellView> square{new CellView(board, squareCol, j, i)};
            m_tiles << square;
        }
    }
    initPieces(board);
}
```

Pieces:

```
void BoardView::initPieces(QGraphicsRectItem* board){
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){

        // pawn
        m_pieces << std::shared_ptr<PieceView> {new PieceView(QString{"white"}, board, 1, i, Qt::white)};
        m_pieces << std::shared_ptr<PieceView> {new PieceView(QString{"black"}, board, 6, i, Qt::black)};

        // rook
        if (i == 0 || i == 7){
            m_pieces << std::shared_ptr<PieceView> {new PieceView(QString{"Chess_rlt60"}, board, 0, i, Qt::white)};
            m_pieces << std::shared_ptr<PieceView> {new PieceView(QString{"Chess_rdt60"}, board, 7, i, Qt::black)};
        }

        // knight
        else if (i == 1 || i == 6){
            m_pieces << std::shared_ptr<PieceView> {new PieceView(QString{"Chess_klt60"}, board, 0, i, Qt::white)};
            m_pieces << std::shared_ptr<PieceView> {new PieceView(QString{"Chess_kdt60"}, board, 7, i, Qt::black)};
        }

        // bishop
        else if (i == 2 || i == 5){
            m_pieces << std::shared_ptr<PieceView> {new PieceView(QString{"Chess_blt60"}, board, 0, i, Qt::white)};
            m_pieces << std::shared_ptr<PieceView> {new PieceView(QString{"Chess_bdt60"}, board, 7, i, Qt::black)};
        }

        // queen
        else if (i == 3){
            m_pieces << std::shared_ptr<PieceView> {new PieceView(QString{"Chess_qlt60"}, board, 0, i, Qt::white)};
            m_pieces << std::shared_ptr<PieceView> {new PieceView(QString{"Chess_qdt60"}, board, 7, i, Qt::black)};
        }

        // king
        else {
            m_pieces << std::shared_ptr<PieceView> {new PieceView(QString{"Chess_klt60"}, board, 0, i, Qt::white)};
            m_pieces << std::shared_ptr<PieceView> {new PieceView(QString{"Chess_kdt60"}, board, 7, i, Qt::black)};
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you might want to call `setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable)` on each of your pieces.

Comment: That is already set in the pieceview.cpp in the constructor.

Comment: Please always try to simplify your problem as much as possible and provide a [mcve]: f.ex. only one or two pieces are relevant in this case, relevant parts and relevant parts of `PieceView` or missing.

Comment: Also try to split up your problem in smaller chunks: (1) Selecting an item (see [`QGraphicsView::itemAt`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#itemAt-1)) and (2) Moving an item (see [`QGraphicsItem::setPos`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#setPos))